# How can AngularJS count fields that are dynamically added by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So using jQuery I am adding list element fields via an add button.  I am not using ng-repeat directive.

```
<li id="blah1" type="text" name="blah1" "ng-model" => "myField[$index]">
<li id="blah2" type="text" name="blah2" "ng-model" => "myField[$index]">
```

Is there a way in AngularJS to get something like the $index variable (or build it) such that a $index like variable will keep getting auto-incremented and is being watched by AngularJS?   This way ng-model in li#blah1 would be myField[1] and li#blah2 would have myField[2].

Comment: I believe you're trying to solve the wrong problem. Why and how are you using jQuery?

Comment: I'm using jQuery via https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon to dynamically add form fields...it's a legacy app so I'm trying to "sprinkle" AngularJS effects/logic on top of these dynamically added form fields.  Since they're dynamically added via jQuery the only way I can try and bind them to angular is to use the $compile function.  But then there's no "ng-repeat" directive handy to access an $index counter.  So perhaps I should try rewriting the form field adding functionality in Angular then?

Comment: Use Angular way to add fields rather than using JQuery

Comment: thanks @JosephtheDreamer, et. al., I've solved the problem, pivoting to the "Angular way" was part of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend doing this using an array in Angular.

JavaScript:

```
var myFields = [];
myFields[0] = { id: 'blah1', name: 'blah1' };
myFields[1] = { id: 'blah2', name: 'blah2' };

$scope.myFields = myFields;
```

HTML:

```
<li id="{{ field.id }}" name="{{ field.name }}" ng-repeat="field in myFields" ng-model="field" /> <!-- Field is equivalent to myFields[$index]. -->
```